# C++11 rvalue reference calling copy constructor too

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-constructor

I've been testing some C++11 features from some some.
I came across r-value references and move constructors.

I implemented my first move constructor, here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class TestClass{

public:
    TestClass(int s):
        size(s), arr(new int[s]){
    }
    ~TestClass(){
        if (arr)
            delete arr;
    }
    // copy constructor
    TestClass(const TestClass& other):
            size(other.size), arr(new int[other.size]){
        std::copy(other.arr, other.arr + other.size, arr);
    }

    // move constructor
    TestClass(TestClass&& other){
        arr=other.arr;
        size=other.size;

        other.arr=nullptr;
        other.size=0;
    }

private:
    int size;
    int * arr;
};

int main(){
    vector<TestClass> vec;

    clock_t start=clock();
    for(int i=0;i<500000;i++){
        vec.push_back(TestClass(1000));
    }
    clock_t stop=clock();
    cout<<stop-start<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine. Anyway putting a std::cout inside the copy constructor i noticed that it gets called! And a lot of times.. (move constructor 500000 times, copy constructor 524287 times).

What surprised me more is that if i comment out the copy constructor from the code, the whole program gets a lot faster, and this time the move constructor is called 1024287 times.

Any clue?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0b61fede4fd9aef84b124760919e8ca8-4c5ca02fa47b506419b4501a6b65fb4f

Comment: @pinoscotto Just a side note: **you have undefined behavior**, you should use `delete[]`, and you don't need the `if (arr) ...` in the destructor. So the destructor should be simply `~TestClass(){ delete[] arr; }`.

Comment: @pinoscotto It is always safe to call `delete[]` without the if: (1) if the `new` throws in the initialization, the destructor won't be called (2) otherwise you either point to a valid address (3) or have a `nullptr` and it is always safe to delete a `nullptr` (guaranteed by the standard).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Put `noexcept` on your move constructor:

```
TestClass(TestClass&& other) noexcept {
```

Elaboration:  I was going to give this one Pierre, but unfortunately the cppreference source is only approximately correct.

In C++03

```
vector<T>::push_back(T)
```

has the "strong exception guarantee".  That means that if the `push_back` throws an exception, the vector is left in the same state it had prior to the call to `push_back`.

This guarantee is problematic if the move constructor throws an exception.

When the `vector` reallocates, it would *like* to **move** the elements from the old buffer to the new.  However if any one of those moves throws an exception (besides the first), then it is left in a state where the old buffer has been modified, and the new buffer doesn't yet contain everything it is supposed to.  The `vector` can't restore the old buffer to its original state because it would have to move elements back to do so, *those* moves might also fail.

So a rule was laid down for C++11:

1. If `T` has a `noexcept` move constructor, that can be used to move the elements from the old buffer to the new.
2. Otherwise if `T` has a copy constructor, that will be used instead.
3. Otherwise (if there is no accessible copy constructor), then the move constructor will be used after all, however in this case, the strong exception safety guarantee is no longer given.

Clarification:  "copy constructor" in rule 2 means a constructor taking a `const T&`, not one of those weenie so-called `T&` copy constructors. :-)

Comment: can you elaborate more on your answer, and what does noexcept do?

Comment: Sod all on Visual studio :-( apart from saying "error C3646: 'noexcept' : unknown override specifier"

Comment: @Alon http://accu.org/index.php/conferences/accu_conference_2013/accu2013_sessions#move_noexcept_and_push_back_and_how_it_relates_to_each_other

Comment: @Alon there is a relevant, albeit pre-C++11 ratification, discussion [here](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/10/exceptionally-moving/). Basically, it is about maintaining certain exception guarantees in standard library containers.

Comment: @doctorlove: In Visual Studio, `throws()` _might_ work, though it means something slightly different which might cause it's own problems.

Comment: @MooingDuck thanks - I'm not sure that VS uses this to optimize though, I 've got lost in macros trying to follow what it does

Comment: So is it intended by the standard? What i find odd with C++11 is that when i discover a useful (on the paper) new sintax, it's always crippled by some corner case that impose accurate handling (with added codex complexity or a never heard before exotic sintax). async is another case

Answer (score 16):

Use `noexcept` on your move constructor :

```
TestClass(TestClass&& other) noexcept { ... }
```

`noexcept` without a constant expression like this is equivalent to `noexcept(true)`.

> The compiler can use this information to enable certain optimizations on non-throwing functions as well as enable the noexcept operator, which can check at compile time if a particular expression is declared to throw any exceptions.
>
> **For example, containers such as std::vector will move their elements if the elements' move constructor is noexcept, and copy otherwise.**

Source : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec

NB : This is a **C++11** feature. Certain compiler may not have implemented it yet... (ex: [Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx))

Answer (score -1):

Copy constructor is called when all reserved memory inside `std::vector` is used. It is necessary to call `std::vector::reserve()` method before adding the elements.

```
vector<TestClass> vec;
vec.reserve(500000);
```