# How do I use unordered_set?

Tags: c++, stl, set, unordered-set

I am trying to define an unordered_set like this:

```
unordered_set<Point> m_Points;
```

When I compile it, I get the following error:

> The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.

Class `Point`:

```
class Point{
    private:
        int x, y;
    public:
        Point(int a_x, int a_y)
            : x(a_x), y(a_y)
        {}
        ~Point(){}

        int getX()const { return x; }
        int getY()const { return y; }

        bool operator == (const Point& rhs) const{
            return x == rhs.x && y == rhs.y;
        }

        bool operator != (const Point& rhs) const{
            return !(*this == rhs);
        }
};
```

- How/where do I define a hash function for **Point**?
- What would be a good hash function for a 2D point?

Comment: There's a pretty good description [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_associative_containers_(C%2B%2B)#Custom_hash_functions).

Comment: A lazy solution might be to derive your class from `std::pair<int, int>`...

Comment: can I define a hash function in class Point and pass that as a functor to unordered_set in second argument of template ?

Comment: @brainydexter Yep - the 2nd argument is class Hash defaulted to std::hash<Key>

Comment: @doctorlove Yea..what I'm trying to figure out is, if I specify a hash function in class Point, how can I specify it as a functor when i define unordered_set ? I am not sure if I can even do that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`std::unordered_set` requires you to write [hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to store and find your own types.

Base types and many types in the `std` namespace do have such hash functions within `std::hash<Key>`. These functions follow [certain rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash):

1. Accepts a single parameter of type `Key`.
2. Returns a value of type `size_t` that represents the hash value of the parameter.
3. Does not throw exceptions when called.
4. For two parameters `k1` and `k2` that are equal, `std::hash<Key>()(k1) == std::hash<Key>()(k2)`.
5. For two different parameters `k1` and `k2` that are not equal, the probability that `std::hash<Key>()(k1) == std::hash<Key>()(k2)` should be very small, approaching `1.0/std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.

Now that we got the definitions out of the way, let's think about what would be a good hash function for your point structure. There was a [request](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2939.html#UK208) that `std::pair` (which is very similar to a point structure) got a hash function, but, unfortunately, that did not make it into the C++11 standard.

But we are lucky: SO is awesome and, of course, you can basically already [find the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2634715/1056003). Note that you do not have to hash integers yourself, because `std::hash` has a specialization for that already. So let's dig into our hash function, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8157967/1056003):

```
namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash<Point>
    {
        size_t operator()(Point const & x) const noexcept
        {
            return (
                (51 + std::hash<int>()(x.getX())) * 51
                + std::hash<int>()(x.getY())
            );
        }
    };
}
```

And we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate reply and links. Can I specify the above hash object-function as a part of my Point class and use that as a functor to, when I define the unordered_set ?

Comment: also, what is the noexcept for ? Is that a standard keyword ?

Comment: noexcept is the promise we give to the compiler that there will be no exception while running the function.

Comment: Aha! Good to know, but it seems, dumb VS2012 hasn't learnt about it yet.

Comment: Also, I think the above hash function is incorrect...for point(2,4) and point(4,2) will be same => (51 + hash(2)) * (51 + hash(4))

Comment: @brainydexter your parantheses are off. it's `(51+hash(2))*51 + hash(4)` which is not equal to `(51+hash(4))*51 + hash(2)` I've edited the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: @brainydexter VS2012 doesn't have noexcept, which is annoying. A discussion about what it means happened here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085383/c11-rvalue-reference-calling-copy-constructor-too

Comment: Furthermore, yes you can include your hash functor within your class as long as it is public and declare `std::unordered_set<Point, Point::hash>`.

Comment: @nijansen VS2012 gives me "error C2923: 'std::unordered_set' : 'Point::Hash' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Hasher'" when I try to make it use a member function

Comment: @doctorlove No idea why, it works in gcc and I don't have MSVC; here is an [ideone sample](http://ideone.com/Zd57Cn)

Comment: I got the signature wrong - I tried a member function, not a member struct. D'oh

Comment: @doctorlove You could technically declare a `size_t operator()(Point const &) noexcept` within `Point` and use `std::unordered_set<Point, Point>` (given that Point has a default constructor, which it doesn't in the above example), but I find that very confusing ;) Also I want to remark that specializing `std::hash` is explicitly encouraged.

Comment: Thanks for the insight nijansen. I was wondering which method is preferred over the other(specializing std::hash over class-member functor)

Comment: Specialise std::hash - it's the expected thing to do.

Comment: @nijansen Why is specializing std::hash preferred? I thought extending std namespace was a bad practice.